# Modulator gain in DCM mode of Buck converter

Tags: circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, transfer-function

I am referring this [document](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva301/slva301.pdf?ts=1591169056331) in Fig 19 the modulator gain is calculated by the formula that results i.e `112.73` with Duty cycle in DCM as `44.72m` for load `250 Ohm` but substituted with `197` gain.

[image: dcm]

Above image is modulator gain used in for the simulation is not used as theoretical value `Amod DCM`as shown below.

[image: dcm]

Can anyone clarify this discrepancy?

Comment: Please explain where you see a discrepancy?

Comment: I have edited for easier understanding the question

Comment: Maybe it's a typo. The previous figure shows the correct gain.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen DCM waveform compared and tweaked in the document do not use theoretical value. As you said can I assume theoretical  is  value which is calculated is right value (gain)?

Comment: @Pai Then about the only thing I can think of is to actually write to the creators of that paper and ask them about the change. Or use their forums.

Comment: If you want to simulate the buck converter in CCM or DCM, use the PWM switch model and, in particular, an auto-toggling version I published a while ago. The models with examples are described in APEC seminars I gave in 2013 and 2014. Link is here to these [seminars](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm).